# Code for EditText box underneath the ScrollView?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-edittext, android-scrollview

Hi there I want to put my EditText box above my ScrollView so the user can still scroll down but at the same time still see the EditText at a fixed view at the top how do I do that ?                                            /                               /

This is my code

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".BitActivity" >

<EditText
                android:id="@+id/input"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Type In Your Value"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:textColor="#2FB3E3"
                android:textSize="30px" >
                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/byte1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/input"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Please Enter a Value"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#FFFF00"
                android:textSize="40px" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: wow you r in such haste to downvote my answer sorry anyway for not providing it heres what I have tried but it just overlaps with the textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `ScrollView` you have `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"`. But the `ScrollView`s parent is the `RelativeLayout` meaning that it will align the top of the `ScrollView` with the top of the `RelativeLayout` (which is the top of the screen).

Try replacing your current `ScrollView` with this::

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/input"
>
```

The key here is this line: `android:layout_below="@id/input"` which align the `ScrollView`s top just below the `View` with id "`input`"'s bottom.

Comment: Im just kinda stuck on how to start should't I do some type of Relativelayout and the edittext is there and the scroll text to hold my long text ?

Comment: @user2283550 Not sure what you mean. You want the EditText above the text right? And the text in a scrollable view below the EditText? So when you scroll the EditText stays at the top of the screen?

Comment: yes you hit the nail it what I said above what I should do or should I try something else ?

Comment: @user2283550 Keep your current code, except you replace your ScrollView with the one I posted. It should force the ScrollView below the EditText

Comment: Sorry for the late reply thanks mate u da don didnt realise that there was android:layout_below="@id/mything" for scrollview safe! :)

Comment: Mav, I'm trying to do something similar, except I want the ScrollView at the top, and the EditText at the bottom with a Button. When I type more than one line into the EditText, I'd like it to expand upward if the ScrollView doesn't fill the whole space, but instead it just scrolls the EditText so the text isn't visible. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ignore me. I had an android:lines=1 getting applied to it from a style. Whoops.